# No serenity report in gradle multi module project

Tags: gradle, serenity-bdd

I have gradle multi module project where one module has BDD serenity api tests

Structure

```
-module1
 - bddTests
 - serenity.properties
-module2
```

I have `serenity.propertie`s file inside the `module1` where I got tests with below entry

```
serenity.outputDirectory=../target/site/serenity
```

But after succes test run I can see empty folder created in the root i.e. `target/site/serenity`

I tried to add another `serenity.properties` file with below in the root as well, No luck though

```
serenity.outputDirectory=target/site/serenity
```

I have single gradle module projects where serenity reports generate perfectly at the root.

Versions:

```
    version("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber6", "2.6.0")
    version("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-reports:", "3.1.0")
    version("io.cucumber:cucumber-core:", "6.10.4")
    version("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-rest-assured", "2.6.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the project I was adding multi modules, and I could solve using the serenity.conf in the project module I was running the bdd tests.

The project structure

- root:

  - module1

    - bddTests
    - serenity.conf
  - module2
  - serenity.properties

And the serenity.conf content:

```
serenity {
  store.html = ALWAYS
  tag.failures = "true"
  outputDirectory=../target/site/serenity
  requirement {
    types = "epic, story"
  }
  report {
    accessibility = true
  }
}
```